Getting "Invalid module format"
I am a newbie using Ubuntu 20.04.
I am learning about Linux module and driver development. I was trying to insert module in kernel, but I am getting the following error:
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module hellomod.ko: Invalid module format

Here is the result of "dmesg":
[ 1311.552922] hellomod: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[ 1311.552976] hellomod: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel

Here is the result of mokutil command:
$ mokutil --sb-state
This system doesn't support Secure Boot

